# How to run a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop

This is my first time making classes in Node.js and I was wondering why I can't run this function.... Can someone point me in the right direction?

```
class Customer {
  constructor() {
    this.shoppingBasket = [];

    function startShopping() {
      const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
      const itemName = prompt("What item is this?");
      const itemPrice = prompt("How much is it?");
      const taxExemption = promt("Is this a food, book or medical product?");
      console.log(`Your item is ${itemName}`);
    }
  }
}

Customer = Customer;
Customer.startShopping();
```

Comment: `startShopping` is a free function inside the constructor - you have to move it out.

Comment: `Customer = Customer;` it should be `let customer = new Customer();` and move your function from the constructor to the class body

Comment: Because `Customer` doesn't have property `startShopping`. The function is only visible inside the constructor.   But there are more things that are weird about your code. I recommend to read more about classes first: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a scopped function in the way you made it here... That means you can't "see" it in the scope your trying to access it from.

You need either to make it a "method" or to attach it to "this".

```
// We normally require/import things at the top, but not nessesarily.
// const PromptSync = require("prompt-sync");

class Customer {
  constructor() {
    this.shoppingBasket = [];


    this.startShoppingPropertyFunction = () => {
      // If imported at top, use this instead:
      // const prompt = new PromptSync();
      const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
      const itemName = prompt("What item is this?");
      const itemPrice = prompt("How much is it?");
      const taxExemption = prompt("Is this a food, book or medical product?");
      console.log(`Your item is ${itemName}`);
    }
  }

  startShoppingMethod() {
    // If imported at top, use this instead:
    // const prompt = new PromptSync();
    const prompt = require("prompt-sync")();
    const itemName = prompt("What item is this?");
    const itemPrice = prompt("How much is it?");
    const taxExemption = prompt("Is this a food, book or medical product?");
    console.log(`Your item is ${itemName}`);
  }
}

const myCustomer = new Customer();
myCustomer.startShoppingMethod();
myCustomer.startShoppingPropertyFunction();
```